# Accessing a bucket at the google S3 api

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, google-api

I am trying to read a bucket at `storage.googleapis.com`, using the Amazon Web Services .Net SDK in C#.

Can anyone provide a working example of a S3 endpoint Config setup for google, just using the Auth. key/secret pair and a bucket name?  Or using any other method to get this working?

According to [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating) this should be a simple matter, but I get all sorts of exceptions when trying to follow the instructions given. Here is an extract of my current attempt - which throws a TrustFailure exception:

> The remote certificate is invalid.

```
AmazonS3Config conf = new AmazonS3Config();
// Set regionEndpoint to null, or else the serviceURL will be ignored
conf.RegionEndpoint = null;
conf.ServiceURL = "https://s3.storage.googleapis.com";
conf.UseHttp = false; 
conf.AuthenticationRegion = null;
conf.UseAccelerateEndpoint = false;
conf.UseDualstackEndpoint = false;

AWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials("GOOG3LFXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "BQ6VeMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");          
IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(cred, conf);

GetBucketVersioningRequest request = new GetBucketVersioningRequest { BucketName = "hisbucket" };
GetBucketVersioningResponse response = client.GetBucketVersioning(request);
```

Comment: add the exceptions you get.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got the .NET SDK to upload to Google Cloud Storage with:

```
            AWSConfigsS3.UseSignatureVersion4 = false;
            AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
            config.ServiceURL = "https://storage.googleapis.com";
            config.SignatureVersion = "2";
            AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, config);
            var transferUtilityConfig = new TransferUtilityConfig
            {
                ConcurrentServiceRequests = 1,
                MinSizeBeforePartUpload = 6291456000,
            };
            var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                FilePath = filePath,
                PartSize = 6291456000,
                Key = keyName,
            };
            TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client, transferUtilityConfig);
            fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
            fileTransferUtility.Dispose();
```

Comment: your code worked for me after 2 days of different settings for this horrible S3-google to work. that config.ServiceURL = "https://storage.googleapis.com"; was the key to success .
why don't they have 10+ votes ?
with only 1 help for others like me: that "keyname" is the full path in the bucket. for example if you have the bucket B and you wand to upload the file1.xml to a subfolder "B/myfolder/file1.xml" then you should put 
BucketName = B and keyname="myfolder/file1.xml" .
Thanks again to chris !!

Answer (score 0):

You need a Amazon S3 service URL, an access key id, a secret access key id and the bucket name.

```
    var s3Config = new AmazonS3Config
    {
        ServiceURL = Constants.AmazonS3ServiceUrl, 
        RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1
    };

    string accessKeyId = Constants.AmazonAccessKeyId;
    string secretAccessKey = Constants.AmazonSecretAccessKey;

    var config = new AwsS3Config(){AmazonS3BucketName = Constants.AmazonS3BucketName};
    var client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, s3Config);
```

Then, you should be able to make calls to the amazon client:

```
var request = new GetObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = _bucketName,
    Key = entity.Path
};

var response = _client.GetObjectAsync(request).Result;
```

The code above works on an S3 account, not particularly storage.googleapis.com, which is your case. Anyway, I hope this helps and answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have it working for Amazon buckets, while the data source is moving to google. The RegionEndpoint class does not make sense for the s3.storage.googleapis - that is part of the issue!  The "Simple Migration" documentation does not give any clue for how to do this with AWS SDK - so I'm no closer to the goal :-|